# Rename or edit row items in Excel Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to find a way to rename/edit row items in my pivot table. I have a field that contains a number value and I would like to add a description to the value.

```
1 ->    1 Complete
2 ->    2 Awaiting confirmation
3 ->    3 Locked
```

Note that my data is coming from an OLAP cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a lookup table with the number-description-mapping in Excel and load it as linked table into the Pivot Table. Afterwards create a connection between your data table and that lookup table.

Now you can use the description in all pivot tables and charts.

In power pivot you don't need to create one giant flat table as you're probably used to in Excel. Keeping the lookup table seperate also helps to update it later if necessary.

Comment: The developers eventually decided to implement this in the EDW. However, I will try this method if needed at a later time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [Microsoft Power Query addon](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379) to do the transforms you want (and to turn them into repeatable queries), before the data goes into the pivot table?